# My ASUS laptop wireless button won't activate in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wireless, asus

I am trying to boot ubuntu from a flash drive,but I can'r find my Wi-Fi connection and the system says that my wireless hardware switch isn't activated. I tried to activate it but it won't change, it still says that my laptop wireless hardware switch is still non-activated.
I entered lspci -knn | Net -A2 and I got the result as following :

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485  Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev01)
            Subsystem: Azureware Device [1a3b:1186]
            Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

here is my rfkill list:

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
                            Soft Blocked: no
                            Hard Blocked: no

1: phy0: Wireess LAN
                Soft Blocked: no
                Hard Bocked: yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT POST IT TO COMMENTS!!!

Comment: @Pilot6 what should I do next?

Comment: Next read my first comment again and try to do what I asked.

Comment: Please also add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: @Pilot6 is there anything else I shoud add?

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless adapter is blocked.

You can unblock it by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf <<< "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4"
```

Reboot after that.

If that does not work try 1,2 or 3 instead of 4.

Comment: Tried them all four, but still can't activate my wireless switch. I noticed something while I was rebooting my ubuntu, it says mod probe failed

Comment: Maybe you made a typo. Check the command.